# Best way to architect a BLoC app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc

My app requires to consume different attributes of a `User` object in different sections of the app i.e. different screens and dialogs.

Example of User attributes would be a list of followers and following.

I need this `User` object to be reactive, i.e. should append a new user (response from api call) to it's following list when the subsequent action is performed.

Currently I plan to use certain BLoC's as Reactive View Models (from MVVM) for each screen (so that the business logic is separated from the presentation layer) and have a global `User BLoC` listening to these View Models.

For example :- `User BLoC` can listen to local View Model BLoC for follow user page and when the view model emits a successful state the response can be added to the `User BLoC's` `User` state's following list.

How feasible and performant would an implementation like this be? Is this the standard way of doing things in BLoC. I looked around for examples like these but could only find simple implementations of BLoC architecture. Would this be too over kill for a mid sized app?

Much appreciated!

Comment: It's Common to have a Global User BLoC.